How to count the number of "No" ocurrencies across multiple columns in R
I have a large dataset and I need to count the total occurrences of "no" across multiple columns.
The dataset looks like this:
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
trat = c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b")
var1 = c("no","no","no","no","yes",NA,NA,"no")
var2 = c("yes","yes","no","no","yes","no",NA,"no")
df = data.frame(id,trat,var1,var2)

Resulting the following table:
  id trat var1 var2
1  1    a   no  yes
2  2    b   no  yes
3  3    a   no   no
4  4    b   no   no
5  5    a  yes  yes
6  6    b <NA>   no
7  7    a <NA> <NA>
8  8    b   no   no

The result I want to achieve is the following:
  id trat var1 var2 count_no
1  1    a   no  yes 1
2  2    b   no  yes 1
3  3    a   no   no 2
4  4    b   no   no 2
5  5    a  yes  yes 0
6  6    b <NA>   no 1
7  7    a <NA> <NA> 0
8  8    b   no   no 2

How can I do that?
Thanks!

An approach using across and rowSums
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(count_no = rowSums(across(var1:var2, ~ .x == "no"), na.rm=T))
  id trat var1 var2 count_no
1  1    a   no  yes        1
2  2    b   no  yes        1
3  3    a   no   no        2
4  4    b   no   no        2
5  5    a  yes  yes        0
6  6    b <NA>   no        1
7  7    a <NA> <NA>        0
8  8    b   no   no        2


This is not a tidyverse solution, but:
df$count_no <- apply(df[,c("var1", "var2")], 1, 
    function(x) sum(x=="no", na.rm= TRUE))

seems to work fine ... in tidyverse, try
df |> 
   dplyr::rowwise() |> 
   dplyr::mutate(count_no = sum(c(var1,var2)=="no", na.rm = TRUE))

